# How to show remove button and remove uploaded file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dropzone.js

Please help me I'm trying to create file uploading with `dropzone.js` and I am having so much hard time finding a way how to remove uploaded files. This is my code:

**index.php**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="file_upload">
    <form action="file_upload.php" class="dropzone">
        <div class="dz-message needsclick">
            <strong>Drop files here or click to upload.</strong><br />
        </div>
    </form>     
</div>
```

**file-upload.php**

```
include_once("db_connect.php");
if(!empty($_FILES)){     
    $upload_dir = "uploads/";
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $uploaded_file = $upload_dir.$fileName;    
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$uploaded_file)){
        //insert file information into db table
        $mysql_insert = "INSERT INTO uploads (file_name, upload_time)VALUES('".$fileName."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')";
        mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_insert) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
    }   
}
```

How can I put a remove button and remove the uploaded file?

Answer (score 6):

### METHOD 1

There is a build in functionality in the library that you can use.

- [**addRemoveLinks**](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-addRemoveLinks) option - see also the bold props

> If true, this will add a link to every file preview to remove or
>   cancel (if already uploading) the file. The **dictCancelUpload**,
>   **dictCancelUploadConfirmation** and **dictRemoveFile** options are used for
>   the wording.

- [**dictRemoveFileConfirmation**](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-dictRemoveFileConfirmation) option

> If this is not null, then the user will be prompted before removing a
>   file.

With the combination of those two properties you will have the build in remove links with confirmation message(*specified in* `dictRemoveFileConfirmation`) which will remove the file from the user interface and to remove it also from the server side you can send AJAX request from [**removedfile**](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-removedfile) event subscription. For example:

> **removedfile**
>
> Called whenever a file is removed from the list. You can listen to
>   this and delete the file from your server if you want to.

```
myDropzone.on('removedfile', function (file) {

    console.log(file);
    /* here do AJAX call to your server ... */

});
```

```js
/* flag is used for testing purpose - to demostrate success and failuer on server */
var flag = false;
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  url: '/upload',
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  dictRemoveFileConfirmation: 'Are you sure that you want to remove this file?',
  init: function() {
    var dz = this;
    dz.on('removedfile', function(file) {
      flag = !flag;
      console.log('file ' + file.name + ' was removed from front-end  ...');
      doAjaxCall(flag).then(function() {
        console.log('file ' + file.name + ' was removed from back-end  ...');
      }, function() {
        console.log('failed to remove file ' + file.name + ' from back-end  ...');
        /* this is a way to restore the file on the front-end
           if something fails on the back-end */
        dz.emit('addedfile', file);
        dz.emit('complete', file);
      });
    });
  }
}

function doAjaxCall(flag) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      flag ? resolve() : reject();
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.1.1/min/basic.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.1.1/min/dropzone.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.1.1/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>

<p>If you upload two files and try to remove them first will demostrate success on server and the second will demostrate failure on server</p>
<div class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone"></div>
```

### METHOD 2

Using a custom theme. Dropzonejs allows you to have a totally custom layout and allows you to overwrite all the default event handlers - then you can fully control the behavior of your dropzone :)

Take a look on [**that sample**](http://www.dropzonejs.com/bootstrap.html).

So basically each `dropzone` has the following default [**layout**](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#layout):

```
<div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
  <div class="dz-details">
    <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name></span></div>
    <div class="dz-size" data-dz-size></div>
    <img data-dz-thumbnail />
  </div>
  <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>
  <div class="dz-success-mark"><span>✔</span></div>
  <div class="dz-error-mark"><span>✘</span></div>
  <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>
</div>
```

This layout is specified in options [**previewTemplate**](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-previewTemplate) option. So what you can do to have a custom remove button is to add element in the template that contains the attribute `data-dz-remove`, for example:

```
<!-- Following button with use the build-in functionality 
     since it has the attribute data-dz-remove -->
<div data-dz-remove class="my-remove-button"></div>
```

But if you want more control, for example to make the AJAX call to server and on successful response to remove the file, you can do it again with custom [**previewTemplate**](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-previewTemplate) and control events by yourself:

```js
var flag = false;
var previewTemplate = 
'<li class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">' +
  '<div class="dz-details">' +
  '  <div class="dz-filename">' +
  '    <span data-dz-name></span>' +
  '    (<span data-dz-size></span>)' +
  '    <span class="btn-remove">Remove</span>' +
  '</div>' +
  '</div>' +
  '<div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>' +
  '<div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>' +
'</li>';

Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  url: '/upload',
  previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
  previewsContainer: '#preview-container',
  init: function() {
    var dz = this;
    dz.on('addedfile', function(file){
      var btnRemove = file.previewElement.querySelector('.btn-remove');
      btnRemove.fileRef = file;
      btnRemove.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        var button = this;
        flag = !flag;
        var keyword = flag ? 'succeed' : 'fail';
        console.log('Sending ajax call that will ' + keyword);
        doAjaxCall(flag).then(function(){
          dz.removeFile(button.fileRef);
          button.fileRef = null;
          console.log('File was removed successfully !');
        }, function(){
          console.log('File was removal failed !');
        });
       
      });
    });
  }
}

function doAjaxCall(flag) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      flag ? resolve() : reject();
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

```css
.btn-remove{
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.btn-remove:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropzone{
  height: 70px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.dropzone .dz-default.dz-message span{
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.dz-preview{
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.1.1/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>

<div id="my-awesome-dropzone" class="dropzone"></div>
<ul id="preview-container"></ul>
```

```
<div class="my-remove-button"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
myDropzone.on('complete', function (file) {
    /* store reference to the file on upload completed */
    file.previewElement.querySelector('.my-remove-button').fileRef = file;
});

document.querySelector('.my-remove-button').onclick = function () {
    doAjaxCall().then(function(response){
        /* use the previously stored reference to remove the file 
           if successfully removed the file from server */
        if(response.result){
            if(this.fileRef){
                myDropzone.removeFile(this.fileRef);
                this.fileRef = null;                 
            }
        }
    });

};
```

Comment: how do I do it? it is not working i use the default layout on my index and it is not showing the remove mark

Comment: Did you specified any options for your dropzone? If you want to use the default remove links then you need to set `addRemoveLinks` in the options for your dropzone. You can do something like `Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = { here put the addRemoveLinks option`, where `myAwesomeDropzone` is the `id` of your dropzone like `id="my-awesome-dropzone"` - this you can use to set options of dropzone if using `autoDiscover = true`

Comment: yes sir I use it on my script part... my problem is on the index.php ... is this the one will i put on? `<div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
  <div class="dz-details">
    <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name></span></div>
    <div class="dz-size" data-dz-size></div>
    <img data-dz-thumbnail />
  </div>
  <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>
  <div class="dz-success-mark"><span>✔</span></div>
  <div class="dz-error-mark"><span>✘</span></div>
  <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>
</div>`

Comment: Do you have trouble with the server side code(_PHP_) to remove file? I will try to provide a front-end example how to create custom links later, just will need to have some free time

Comment: @JkBoy I added two code snippets that you can expand and play with if you click **Show code snippet**. Let me know if you understand how it works now or if any other questions appear. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just set addRemoveLinks to true.

```
//"myDropzone" is the camelized version of the form ID
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    addRemoveLinks: true,
};
```